# What are all the steps involved with changing an Alexa Skill name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, echo, alexa-skills-kit

I submitted a skill to Amazon for Alexa, and it failed certification due to intellectual property rights.  Amazon suggested that I say the service is "for" the IP rights holder, so I modified the name and am now getting this error for everything I try to do.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'application' of undefined"
}
```

So far, I updated the Skill Name, Invocation Name, and Welcome Message.  Is there something else I need to update or run on the dev portal to get this to work again?

Update: When I try to start the skill from the Alexa Development portal, I see this in the logs for

console.log("event.session.application.applicationId=" + event.session.application.applicationId);

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "session": {
        "new": true,
        "sessionId": "SessionId.8b65b2f5-0193-4307-9bef-88c116d9344b",
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.5987b947-c8e9-4fc4-a0b8-2ba12c57ea59"
        },
        "attributes": null,
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.ABCDEFG" // masked my account value
        }
    },
    "request": {
        "type": "IntentRequest",
        "requestId": "EdwRequestId.4d19f589-cdca-4303-99dc-0dc5cec781d2",
        "timestamp": "2016-04-18T16:21:04Z",
        "intent": {
            "name": "DontKnowIntent"
        }
    }
}
```

The application ID matches the one supplied in the Alexa Development portal, so I don't think that's causing any issues.  The property 'application' is only ever called after 'session', which clearly is defined.  I don't know if the null attributes is causing an error.  Maybe someone can look at a successful request?

Finally, here is my code: https://github.com/Shwheelz/alexa-skills-kit-js/blob/master/my_skills/pokemonTrivia/src/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the name twice before on a node app and a Java 8 app.  All I had to do was change the name (also changed invocation name) under the skill information.  It worked first time out.   Now my skill name did not update on alexa app once and did the other time.   Since you are not certified, you may want to create the skill for scratch.  This should only take about 5 or 10 mins.  Just do not forget to change or add the new application Id of  you lambda